# Does anybody know what kind of font is written in this document?

Tags: fonts, typography

**I've been looking forward to know which is this kind of font in LaTeX. I've tried with these changes in my preamble document:**

```
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{cmss}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

But that doesn't work. I attached an image as I want to see in my pdfLaTeX document [image]

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with the user that it seems to be Palladio, I add a complete code so that you can compare it better on your computer using `pdfLaTeX`. The text font provided is URW Palladio with the option `pxfonts` for the mathematical part.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Hoy es un espléndido día soleado.
\[f(n)=2n, \quad \overbrace{ 1+2+\cdots+100 }^{n(n+1)/2}\]
\[\iint\limits_{\mathcal O} dx\,dy=\mathrm{area}(\mathcal O)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the tool pdffonts: Look at here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15JJ-X6EJsvl8o1EpBy2g55x0-G2JVG-y/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

I want to say it looks like [Palladio](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwpalladio/) or a related font.

However, as per [texnician](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician)'s comment if you have access to the PDF you should be able to find the font the the file properties: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Comment: Yes you're right it's Palladio Font effectively. Thanks for your answer
Many greetings from Mexico

Comment: [See this:] https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PCToUM3ezMcxljyTeznVRhnUaHheNgpn/view?usp=sharing